# Using non default HTTPS port without writing it in URL on Jetty/Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, dns, jetty, jetty-9

Jetty `9.3.8.v20160314` running on AWS EC2 Linux machine with Java `1.8.0_51` has two virtual hosts defined under two different contexts - `webapps/app1` and `webapps/app2` with an empty `webapps/ROOT` directory.

Each web context has its own SSL connector with proper keystore assigned, of two different domain names, let's say `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com`.

The problem is that each SSL connector has to use a different port, so first app would have port `443` but the second use `444`, which is not the default port for HTTPS calls. Now, app2's clients would have to use `https://www.example2.com:444` which is not pretty.

**Is there some workaround to omit the `:444` part?**

Maybe it is possible to define a something on WebAppContext.xml to forward calls to port `444`, or maybe in the DNS zone file?

Perhaps this can be done on the Linux level, using `iptables`?

Content of `webapps/appX.xml` -

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war">
    <SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/appX
  </Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
     <Array type="java.lang.String">
       <Item>www.exampleX.com</Item>
     </Array>
  </Set>

  <!-- by Code Range -->
  <Get name="errorHandler">
    <Call name="addErrorPage">
      <Arg type="int">400</Arg>
      <Arg type="int">599</Arg>
      <Arg type="String">/</Arg>
    </Call>
  </Get>
</Configure>
```

Contents of `etc/jetty-ssl.xml` -

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
    ... 
  <Call  name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="sslConnector2" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
          </Array>
        </Arg>

        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port">8444</Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
   ...
</Configure>
```

SSL connector is set to port `8444` and forwarded by `iptables` from external port `444` -

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 444 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround to omit the port. If you specify an HTTPS URL without a port, you are in fact implicitly specifying port 443.

I would suggest looking into placing an Nginx reverse proxy in front of your Jetty applications, and have it forward requests to the appropriate port based on the domain name being requested.